# query in php while loop firing but giving results of one variable

Tags: php, mysql, timetable

[image]i have a timetable application which needs to generate timetables for all teachers in one go based on the semester. i am querying teacher id(s) and inside the while loop i am using the same code used to generate an individual teacher's timetable. according to mysql logs, query is firing for every teacher id but same timetable is being generated for all teachers.
i checked every line of code but its somehow not working.

I am so stuck on this, please help.

my php code:

```
<?php
include ("includes/functions.php");
$timespan = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['timespan']);

$q11 = "select * from teachers order by teacher";
$r11 = mysql_query($q11) or die(mysql_error());
while($rows11 = mysql_fetch_array($r11)){

$teacher = $rows11['id'];

$array_day=array('Mon' => 0, 'Tue' => 1, 'Wed' => 2, 'Thu' => 3, 'Fri' => 4, 'Sat' =>      5);

if($timespan=="BS"){
 $qs="";
}
else if ($timespan=="MS"){
 $qs=" and (partno='1' or partno='3' or partno='5' or partno='9') ";
}
else if ($timespan=="WS"){
$qs=" and (partno='2' or partno='4' or partno='6' or partno='9') ";
}
else if ($timespan=="1"){
$qs=" and partno='1' ";
}
else if ($timespan=="2"){
$qs=" and partno='2' ";
}
else if ($timespan=="3"){
$qs=" and partno='3' ";
}
else if ($timespan=="4"){
$qs=" and partno='4' ";
}
else if ($timespan=="5"){
$qs=" and partno='5' ";
}
else if ($timespan=="6"){
$qs=" and partno='6' ";
}
else if ($timespan=="7"){
$qs=" and partno='7' ";
}
else if ($timespan=="8"){
$qs=" and partno='8' ";
}
else if ($timespan=="10"){
$qs=" and partno='1' ";
}
else if ($timespan=="11"){
 $qs=" and partno='2' ";
}
else if ($timespan=="9"){
$qs=" and partno='9' ";
}

if($qs==""){
$q1="SELECT tt.day as day, tt.period as period, tt.egstatus as egstat, tt.resp_id as id,    tt.sub_group, tt.filter, c.shortname as c_s, p.shortname as p_s, tt.teacherid, tt.subjectid as subject, r.room as room, t.apd1 as apd1, t.apd2 as apd2, g.groupname as class,  t.teacher as teacher, p.courseid as course, p.partno as part FROM course c, papers p, ttresponsibility tt, teachers t, groups g, rooms r  where c.id=p.courseid and p.paperid = tt.subjectid and tt.teacherid= t.id and tt.room=r.room_id and tt.groupname=g.group_id and tt.teacherid = '$teacher' order by tt.day,tt.period,p.partno ASC";
}else{
$q1="SELECT tt.day as day, tt.period as period, tt.egstatus as egstat, tt.resp_id as id, tt.sub_group, tt.filter, c.shortname as c_s, p.shortname as p_s, tt.teacherid, tt.subjectid as subject, r.room as room, t.apd1 as apd1, t.apd2 as apd2, g.groupname as class,  t.teacher as teacher, p.courseid as course, p.partno as part FROM course c, papers p, ttresponsibility tt, teachers t, groups g, rooms r  where c.id=p.courseid and p.paperid = tt.subjectid and tt.teacherid= t.id and tt.room=r.room_id and tt.groupname=g.group_id and tt.teacherid = '$teacher'" .$qs. " order by tt.day,tt.period,p.partno ASC";
}

$r1 = mysql_query($q1) or die ("responsibility fetch error:" .mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($r1) > 0){
$q2 = "select teacher,name2,type from teachers where id = '$teacher'";
$r2 = mysql_query($q2) or die("teacher fetch error:" .mysql_error());
$rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($r2);
//$num = mysql_num_rows($r1);


echo "<table width=100% style='border:0px ;font-family:arial;font-size:10px; border-  collapse:collapse;cellspacing:0;padding:0px;'><tr><td width=50% align=left border=0 style='border:0px ;font-family:arial;font-size:10px; border-collapse:collapse;cellspacing:0;padding:0px;'>Dated: 31st July 2012</td><td  style='border:0px ;font-family:arial;font-size:10px; border-collapse:collapse;cellspacing:0;padding:0px;' width=50% align=right border=0>Version 2.0</td></tr></table>";


echo "<center><font size=5><strong>Shri Ram College of Commerce</strong></font></center>";

echo "<br>";

echo "<table width=100%><tr><td align=left  style='border:0px ;font-family:arial;font-size:10px; border-collapse:collapse;cellspacing:0;padding:0px;' ><font size=4><strong>Teacher: ";
if($rows1['type']==1){
echo "".$rows1['name2']."";
}else{
echo "".$rows1['teacher']."";
}
echo "</strong></h3></font></b></td>";
if ($timespan=="MS"){
echo "<td align=right  style='border:0px ;font-family:arial;font-size:10px; border-collapse:collapse;cellspacing:0;padding:0px;'><font size=4><strong>Time Span: Monsoon Term</strong></font></br></td></tr></table>";
}
else if ($timespan=="WS"){
echo "<td align=right  style='border:0px ;font-family:arial;font-size:10px; border-     collapse:collapse;cellspacing:0;padding:0px;'><font size=4><strong>Time Span: Winter Term</strong></font></br></td></tr></table>";
}
echo "<br>";

echo "<table width='100%' border='1' class='tt'>";

echo "<tr class='heads'>";
echo "<td rowspan='2' style='padding:0;text-align:center; width:1%;'>  <b>Period<br>Time</b></td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; '><b>I</b></td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; '><b>II</b></td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; '><b>III</b></td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; '><b>IV</b></td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; '><b>V</b></td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; width:1%;' ><b>Break</b></td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; '><b>VI</b></td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; '><b>VII</b></td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; '><b>VIII</b></td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; '><b>IX</b></td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 echo "<tr class='heads'>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; '><b>8:40 AM</b></td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; '><b>9:35 AM</b></td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; '><b>10:30 AM</b></td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; '><b>11:25 AM</b></td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; '><b>12:20 PM</b></td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; '><b>1:15 PM</b></td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; '><b>2:00 PM</b></td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; '><b>2:55 PM</b></td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; '><b>3:50 PM</b></td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0;text-align:center; '><b>4:45 PM</b></td>";
echo "</tr>";

$k="ToFetchNextRow";
$l = 0;
$rowToProcess=0;
$toRepeat=1;
$num=mysql_num_rows($r1);
$num1=$num-1;    

for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){

$day = array_search($i, $array_day);

echo "<tr class='period'><td style='padding:0;text-align:center;'>    
<b>".$day."</b></td>";
for($j=0;$j<=8;$j++){
if($i==0 and $j==5){
  echo "<td style='xycell' rowspan=6 >&nbsp;</td>";
 }

 $noOfEntriesAddedInThisCell=0;
 $toRepeat=1;
 while($toRepeat==1){
   $rows = mysql_fetch_array($r1);
   $data[] = $rows; // creating multidimensional array

   $dt = $data[$rowToProcess]['day']; 
   $period = $data[$rowToProcess]['period'];
   $paper = $data[$rowToProcess]['p_s'];
   $course = $data[$rowToProcess]['c_s'];
   $room = $data[$rowToProcess]['room'];
   $class = $data[$rowToProcess]['class'];
   $id = $data[$rowToProcess]['id'];
   $part = $data[$rowToProcess]['part'];
   $subgroup = $data[$rowToProcess]['sub_group'];
   $weekselector = $data[$rowToProcess]['filter'];
$egstatus = $data[$rowToProcess]['egstat'];  

    //process the row to be processed

    //add the cell entry if it is of interest
   if(($i+1) == $dt and ($j+1) == $period){
// check if the slot is busy
   if($egstatus == 1){

 echo "<td style='xycell' valign=center align=center  class='tt'><b><div style='border-   bottom:0px solid #bbb;padding:0;font-family:arial;font-size:11px'>   <center>Contact<br>Hour</center></td>";
   }
elseif($egstatus == 2){

echo "<td  style='xycell' valign=center align=center><b><div style='border-bottom:0px     solid #bbb;padding:0;font-family:arial;'><a class='slot' style='border-bottom:0px solid #ccc;' href='#' id='status".$dt."+".$period."' onclick='editSlot(".$dt.','.$period.','.$teacher.','.$id."); return false'>Busy</td>";
   }

elseif($egstatus == 0){
  $e = $i + 1;
      $f = $j + 1;
      if($noOfEntriesAddedInThisCell==0){
      echo "<td valign=center align=center style='border:2px solid #000;padding:0;font-family:arial;'";

      if($subgroup!=0){
        echo "class='orangeBlock'";
      }else{
        echo "class='yellowBlock'";
      }

      echo "><b>";
      }
      echo "<table class='' style='border:0px solid #000;font-family:arial;border-collapse:collapse;cellspacing:0;padding:0px;'>";
      echo "<tr>";

      echo "<td style='border-collapse:collapse;border:0px ;font-size:11px; font-family: arial, arial,helvetica, sans-serif;' valign='top'><b> ".$course."-".$part." ".$class."";

if($subgroup!=0){
echo "".$subgroup." "; 
}
echo "".$paper." ".$room."";

if($weekselector==1){
echo "(O)</td>";
}

if($weekselector==2){
echo "(E)</td>";
}


echo "</td></tr></table>";
     }
      $noOfEntriesAddedInThisCell = $noOfEntriesAddedInThisCell+1;

     if($rowToProcess < $num1){

       $rowToProcess=$rowToProcess+1;
     }else{ 
       $toRepeat=0;
     }

}else{
        if($noOfEntriesAddedInThisCell !=0){
        //close the internal table cell
        echo "</td>";
     }else{

  //fill the empty cell
       $r = $i + 1;
       $s = $j + 1;

       echo "<td  valign='top' class='tt'><br><br><br></td>";

  }
     $toRepeat=0;
   }

  }//while closing

 }//jloop closing

}// closing i
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

echo "<br><br><br><br>";

echo "<table width=100% style='border:0px ;font-family:arial;font-size:11px; border-collapse:collapse;cellspacing:0;padding:0px;'>";

echo "<tr><td  style='border:0px ;font-family:arial;font-size:11px; border-collapse:collapse;cellspacing:0;padding:0px;' align=left style=font-size:11px> Convenor</td>  <td  style='border:0px ;font-family:arial;font-size:11px; border-collapse:collapse;cellspacing:0;padding:0px;' align=center style=font-size:11px>Teacher Incharge</td><td  style='border:0px ;font-family:arial;font-size:11px; border-collapse:collapse;cellspacing:0;padding:0px;' align=right style=font-size:11px>Principal</td></tr>";

echo "<tr><td  style='border:0px ;font-family:arial;font-size:11px; border-collapse:collapse;cellspacing:0;padding:0px;' align=left style=font-size:11px style='border-collapse:collapse;border:0px solid #000;'> Vikas Madan</td><td  style='border:0px ;font-family:arial;font-size:11px; border-collapse:collapse;cellspacing:0;padding:0px;' align=center style=font-size:11px>Amit Sachdeva</td><td  style='border:0px ;font-family:arial;font-size:11px; border-collapse:collapse;cellspacing:0;padding:0px;' align=right style=font-size:11px>P. C. Jain</td></tr>";

echo "</table>";

}

else{

echo "";
}

}

?>
```

edited code snippet:

```
   while($toRepeat==1){
   while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($r1)){
   $data[] = $rows; // creating multidimensional array

   $dt = $data[$rowToProcess]['day']; 
   $period = $data[$rowToProcess]['period'];
   $paper = $data[$rowToProcess]['p_s'];
   $course = $data[$rowToProcess]['c_s'];
   $room = $data[$rowToProcess]['room'];
   $class = $data[$rowToProcess]['class'];
   $id = $data[$rowToProcess]['id'];
   $part = $data[$rowToProcess]['part'];
   $subgroup = $data[$rowToProcess]['sub_group'];
   $weekselector = $data[$rowToProcess]['filter'];
$egstatus = $data[$rowToProcess]['egstat'];  
 }
```

and the output afterwards.
[image: after the edited code as advised by colin]

Comment: Do not use the `mysql_*` functions in your code. These functions are no longer maintained and will be deprecated for good in PHP 5.5. Instead, you should use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). Don't know which to use? [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) should help.

Comment: Also, you don't have to `echo` every HTML line. You can break out of PHP mode with the `?>` tag, then have your HTML code, then get back into PHP mode with `<?php`. See the [Escaping from HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) page for more.

Comment: @JonahBishop thanks for the advice on best practices, but here i need help to make this work.. please let me know if u can help me with this code

Answer (score 1):

You need to create another while loop while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($r1)) { } You currently don't have this in a loop thus the repeating value.

---

Take this out of the loop:

```
$array_day=array('Mon' => 0, 'Tue' => 1, 'Wed' => 2, 'Thu' => 3, 'Fri' => 4, 'Sat' =>      5);
```

I am not quite sure what you are asking. What do you mean it results of only one variable. Do you mean the first variable in the loop is the only one being returned correctly or on the second loop no variables are being returned correctly?

Comment: @Jonah Bishop, I am not sure I would recommend that. You sure don't have to use a separate echo statement though. You could combine that into one or two larger ones.

Comment: i mean that the timetable which has to be generated for all queries of different teacher ids in the loop is not being done. Although the timetable layout with cell entries is being generated which is equal to the no of teachers but every tt has the same entry as the first one

Comment: What is the variable (with array key) that has the same value on the subsequent as it does on the first loop?

Comment: taking out the above line wont help as it is outputting the name of the day in the first column. also i have edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: No it won't, but there is no need to redeclare $array_day on each loop when it is static.

Comment: "but every tt has the same entry as the first one" <- I doesn't have the same entry it doesn't have any value after the first loop. (Reference screenshot). Right?

Comment: the values from the multidimensional array $data is being outputted for evry query fired. it should echo individual data for every query fired according to teacher ids but it is giving the same output for all teachers even though the query for every teacher id is being fired inside the loop. i have triple checked my mysql logs.

Comment: TT(s) are being generated one after the other but it all has same values. its not possible the show the entire page thats why i showed u one tt of first teacher and after this tt is generated for every teacher with the same values as in the first one as shown in the image.

Comment: i have taken out the array_day line out of the loop but i think that is still not the problem. this site is asking again and again to move to chat. Can i ask you for that?

Comment: No you are right it isn't the actual issue it was just a side note. I am still having a look at this. There is quite a bit of code to sort through here.

Comment: please do look through and let me know as i have pulled my hair on this and the strange thing is that it is returning different teacher's  names on top of every tt layout but the entries are the same as of the first one. I am digging in again on this.

Comment: Got it...

You need to create another while loop with this as the delimiter

$rows = mysql_fetch_array($r1);

Does that make sense?

Comment: i am not sure what you are trying to ask me to do? are u saying that  inside the j loop after the line while(toRepeat == 1) i should start another while loop for $rows. i have done that and that has made the output go haywire totally. doing this is returning only one entry per tt and that too same for every teacher.

Comment: Indeed, that is exactly it. Would you mine adding the code snippet to demonstrate how you implemented the loop as well as another screenshot of the output?

Comment: i have edited the code and added the screenshot too. check please and let me know if i did it wrong.

Comment: the same thing is repeated for every teacher with same values in monday first period after the edited code.

Comment: i just checked ur edited answer and applied that but it still doesnt give me the output. i  hope you dont want me to keep it empty. and when i close it just before the outer while closes it is loading infinitely.

Comment: No of course not empty, but to have the curly braces surround the necessary code. I will have a look in just a minute.

Comment: hey colin if u have anything please let me know.

Comment: Yes, you implemented the loop incorrectly. It needs to surround everything. The } should be after $toRepeat=0;

Comment: i did what u suggested and after putting the closing brace after $torepeat=0, the page is left loading forever and never stops. i think it is going into an infinite loop